# Trying to loop through a range of dates but getting object is not callable

Tags: python

Im trying to loop through a range of dates and store the results in a list.

Im getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not callable

start = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
dateList = []
end = 30
for i in range(0, end, 1):
    dateList.append(start - timedelta(days=i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the "datetime" module for this code to work. If you type:

```
from datetime import *
```

at the top of your code then it will work. However, this kind of import is considered bad practice in Python so it would be better if you referred to the "datetime" module directly:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dateList = []
end = 30
for i in range(0, end, 1):
    dateList.append(start - datetime.timedelta(days=i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Timedelta returns the parts that make it up in a tuple object (days, seconds, microseconds). You must extract an element to use in addition/subtraction in your start variable assignment

They are accessed individually using

```
var.days, var.seconds, var.microseconds
```

You also didn't import datetime module for the code to work. I recommend this code.

```
import datetime

td = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start = datetime.today() - td.days
....
td = datetime.timedelta(days=i)
dateList.append(start - td.days)
```